# onActivityCreated is deprecated. For DialogFrament what is the replacement for onViewCreated if not get called

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Based on the document:

> use onViewCreated(View, Bundle) for code touching the Fragment's view and onCreate(Bundle) for other initialization. To get a callback specifically when a Fragment activity's Activity.onCreate(Bundle) is called, register a androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver on the Activity's Lifecycle in onAttach(Context), removing it when it receives the Lifecycle.State.CREATED callback.

I know that onViewCreated can be used if need to touch the Fragment's view. But for DialgFragment if not overwriting onCreateView then `onViewCreated` will not be called. In this case what is the replacement for onViewCreated in DialgFragment?

Comment: What would you be looking to do in `onViewCreated()`? If you are using `onCreateDialog()` instead of `onCreateView()`, you need to do all your widget work in `onCreateDialog()`.